# Weird behavior of linkbutton within updatepanel

Tags: asp.net

This problem is relevent apperantly to IE6 and maybe to newer versions im not sure. when you put a linkbutton inside an updatepanel like so:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton runat="server">Test</asp:LinkButton>
       </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You run it and then play around with ctrl+mouse wheel and change the size of the site. Then click the linkbutton. It changes the size of the text of the website again to somekind of deffault size... Im wondering if someone knows how to fix this. And what is causing this problem

Edit: the problem was with a few users clicking the link and suddenly all the text on the page became very small and unreadable

Comment: It would have been helpful(and not so difficult) if you'd tested it in other browsers as well. And maybe it does not only appy to LinkButtons but to Async Postbacks in general.

Comment: the problem does not exist in chrome... the problem is that im developing the application to be used within a private enterprise and they are using IE6...

Comment: If all users want to resize this form, you should consider to change the CSS by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to fix here, **this is a browser behavior**.

But if you have a custom behavior that you change the text size, then you need to take care to save the last setting somewhere and then get the last setting and use it.

Comment: why does it happen? is there no way to work around it? because it is annoying to the users...

Comment: I do not think that users change the size of the browser content so much - or I do not understand what really is the problem. Anyway this is a browser issue and you can not do much.